# Difficulty with socket communication from Server to Client

Tags: java, sockets

I have a relatively simple program where I try establish Client Server connection and at the same time I use threads in the client side to allow for multiple connections.

I run the server and then the server invokes the client constructor and passes the port connection to the client and the thread is started on the client side.

The problem I have is that when I run the server side it doesn't want to go beyond the constructor call. It seems to get stuck at the constructor.

Sorry all this sounds a bit confusing

Any thoughts perhaps

this is the server side

```
ServerMultipleThreads()
{


    System.out.println("Starting the server first...");
    try
    {
        ServerSoc = new ServerSocket(7777);
        listening = true;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.exit(1);

    }

    System.out.println("The server has started running");

    while(listening)
    {
        try
        {
            //creating the client socket and starting the new client session
            new ClientSession(ServerSoc.accept());
            System.out.println("The clientSession was called");
            in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            while(true)
            {
                line = is.readLine();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myFile,txt")), true);
                out.println(line);
            }


        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
                System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

and this is on client side

```
ClientSession(Socket s)
{
    clientSocket = s;

    try
    {


        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        out.println("Welcome");

    }
    catch(IOException exe)
    {
        System.out.println(exe.toString());

    }
    //starting the thread
    while(runner == null)
    {
        runner = new Thread(this);
        runner.start();
    }
}

public void run()
{
    while(runner == Thread.currentThread())
    {
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String stdIn;

        try
        {
            while((stdIn = buf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                out.println(stdIn);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException exe)
        {
            exe.toString();

        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){}

    }
```

Kind regards
Arian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `ServerSocket.accept()` blocks until it receives a client request.
You need to have a client calling the server, something like this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
// write some data...
```